# VBA macro to get Outlook attachments only works when Outlook is closed

Tags: vba, excel, ssis, outlook

Excel 2010 & SSIS 2012 - when Outlook is open and the macro is ran I get an Run-time error 429 - ActiveX couldn't create object...when Outlook is closed the macro performs as expected - it down loads all attachments that begin with Mini Report and ends in xlsx.

The SSIS package opens the Excel file with the macro but then returns the ActiveX error.  Again, if Outlook is closed, the SSIS package opens Excel, runs the macro (downloading the files) and saves them in our shared drive directory.

What have I coded that would require Outlook to be closed?

VBA code as follows:

```
Sub GetAttachments()

Dim olapp As Object
Dim olmapi As Object
Dim olmail As Object
Dim olitem As Object
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim olattach As Object
Dim FileName As String

Const num As Integer = 6
Const path As String = "Y:\Wireline Forecast\MiniReport - Production\Mini Report Region Automation\Load Files\"
Const strFileType As String = "xlsx"

Set olapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set olmapi = getnamespace("MAPI")
Set olmail = olmapi.getdefaultfolder(num)

If olmail.Items.restrict("[UNREAD]=True").Count = 0 Then

    MsgBox ("No Unread mails")

    Else
        For Each olitem In olmail.Items.restrict("[UNREAD]=True")
            If olitem.attachments.Count <> 0 Then
                For Each olattach In olitem.attachments
                    If Left(olattach.FileName, 11) = "Mini Report" And Right(olattach.FileName, 4) = "xlsx" Then
                    FileName = "Y:\Wireline Forecast\MiniReport - Production\Mini Report Region Automation\Load Files\" & olattach.FileName
                    olattach.SaveAsFile FileName
                    End If
                Next olattach
            End If
        Next olitem
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if Outlook and Excel are running in different security contexts. Make sure that either both or neither apps are running with elevated privileges (Run As Administrator).

Comment: IT has it locked down so no ability to run as Admin so both programs should be running at the same security level.

Comment: How are Excel and Outlook launched?

Answer (score 0):

Actually found out that Outlook was "locked" when it was open so that explained the ActiveX error so I built a work around....I just added a script task that closes Outlook so the next Script Task can get the attachments then another Script Task that reopens Outlook.  Not the prettiest or cleanest but it works for now.